# Rust Serde: field with deserialize_with which depends on 2 other fields throws error `missing field`

Tags: rust, serde

I can demonstrate my problem with this simple code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "full_name_deserializer")]
    full_name: String,
}

fn full_name_deserializer<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let person: Person = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;    
    Ok(format!("{} - {}", person.first_name, person.last_name))
}

let data = r#"
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }"#;

match serde_json::from_str::<Person>(data) {
    Ok(p) => println!("Me: {:?}",p),
    Err(e) => println!("Error: {:?}",e)
}
```

This throws error: `Error("missing field` full_name`", line: 5, column: 9)`

The `full_name` field will obviously be missing in the json because I want it to be initialized as the concatenation of 2 other fields. How can I do that?

**EDIT:** one idea I have is to remove `deserialize_with` and to add `skip_deserializing` to the `full_name` field and then post process the struct to add the full_name after the deserialization is complete. I am not sure how to hook into the time when deserialization is complete? Is there a built in way? Or will I have to do it manually?

I did come across this:

https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/642

which talks about "Add finalizer attribute hook to validate a deserialized structure". That might get me what I need. But I don't think it's been added to serde yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because it is missing the field. `deserialize_with` gives you a deserializer for the field you want to deserialize, not the parent structure. The way it is currently written, it expects to find data which looks like this:

```json
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "full_name": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }
}
```

That being said, it would still not work because the implementation of `Person::deserialize` would call itself in an infinite loop until it eventually finds the inner field missing or overflows the stack.

You can fix this by implementing `Deserialize` for the entire type, instead of just the derived field. Alternatively, you may find it easier to use `serde(from = "...")` like so:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(from = "PersonData")]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    full_name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct PersonData {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
}

impl From<PersonData> for Person {
    fn from(data: PersonData) -> Self {
        Person {
            full_name: format!("{} - {}", data.first_name, data.last_name),
            first_name: data.first_name,
            last_name: data.last_name,
        }
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae1335502a2467dbacacfdb467c2c0a6)

Comment: The original code is actually expecting infinitely recursive JSON, and will infinitely recurse when given such a thing.

Comment: @Locke is there a way to avoid the duplication of the `first_name: String, last_name: String` ? Once in `Person` and again in `PersonData`?

Or, is there something which allows post-processing after a struct is deserialized?

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation, there is no duplication in the implementation for `From` since it just moves the existing strings into the new structure without reallocating or copying again. You could further improve this though by making it truly zero-copy by using `&'de str` instead of `String`  for `first_name` and `last_name`. This would however require the use of lifetimes. I would also recommend switching `full_name` to a method instead if it is not used very frequently.

Comment: @Locke I mean the duplication of code. Look at your code - the `first_name: String, last_name: String` is being having to copy pasted.

Comment: @sudoExclaimationExclaimation, this is probably as short as you are going to get without sacrificing readability. If you implemented deserialize manually you would end up with far more code from implementing a `Visitor` for the type. If you have a struct with many more fields and are worried about the duplication for that reason, you may want to look into finding or writing a macro to help you. I suppose you could also do `serde(from = "serde_json::Value")`, but you would incur a performance hit.

Comment: @Locke Thanks for the help. I ended up creating a wrapping struct with custom deserializer and the full_name field.

Comment: @Locke just as a note, deserializing JSON strings into `&'de str` is almost always wrong because you loose the ability to have escape sequences within those strings. i.e. try deserializing `"hello\nworld"`.

Comment: @cafce25 I hadn't thought about that before. Generally I use `Cow<'de, str>` in my own projects since it allows me to create an owned instance of the data, but I chose to mention `&str` here to make it a bit easier to understand. It seems like I had thus far managed to avoided that issue by chance due to my type choice. I'll keep that in mind if I ever find myself suggesting a zero-copy solution again.